# Is radix sort the only non-comparison sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, radix-sort, radix

As the title says, is radix sort the only non-comparison sorting algorithm? My guess is yes.

Comment: What do you mean by *non-comparison*? All sorts have to compare *something*, unless you have no more than one item per bucket.

Comment: @Loadmaster: The name is slightly misleading - it means a sort that doesn't compare elements atomically.

Comment: Spaghetti sort (if suitable hardware is available)...

Comment: Sleep sort would also be considered non-comparative I think...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - there's counting sort and bucket sort also, among others. Check the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Any set can be sorted by not using comparisons.

The process is

- decide on a manageable size of input domain M you can handle to record in a manageable array. For chars(8-bit) the domain would be 0-255.
- split the input in some orderly fashion into the array.
- repeat and rinse if the input is still not completely considered i.e. all bits in M has not been considered.

For example an 32 bit, M, integer sort could be carried out as:

- look at the first 8 bits, put (references, pointers or what your lang has available), in the 8-bit range. put them in an array [0-255], now you have a coarse(ballpark) ordering of your values.
- look at the next 8 bits, put them in a similar array, keep a reference to the first ordering. 
  The next 8x2 bits are handled the same way. To extract you follow the links from the first set.

Radix sort uses digits and have 2 variants, (MSB to LSB) and (LSB to MSB).

Counting sort uses only the first step

Bucket sort is usually mentioned when referring to a mix of counting and a comparison sorts.

Interestingly, for quite a few use-cases, comparison sorts comes up short.